# Combo Box not showing on Excel VBA Form

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a form with multiple Combo boxes.  I was doing some appearance tweaking of the form and one of the boxes is not showing anywhere.  If I try to add a new combobox with the same name it says it is not unique.
I tried Opening the form with a message in the box "Here I am" but it did not show.  I don't get any compile errors as there are multiple references to the field in my code. Is there anyway to find it (Me.cmb_Photographer)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that this site is not a free coding site. Individuals here are more than willing to help you but you must provide examples of what you have tried already, actual result, and expected result. Please visit this page for more information on how to best ask your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this, as mentioned in previous comments, your question is broad and lacks enough details to fully understand what you mean by *...one of the boxes is not showing anywhere.* Is the `ComboBox` not visible in the design view of your form or on the running version of your form or both?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bunch of different things. Perhaps the visible property is set to No or the control is behind another control. You might also have mislabeled something so Name property is different from the Control Source property.

In any case you should be able to go into design mode, open the property sheet and use the dropdown to find the control you're looking for. It should highlight the control on the form.

[image]